# Question about inequalities and sets

Tags: inequality

> **Theorem**: For every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, show there exists a unique $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $n\leq x<n+1$.

*Prove for that $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there is exactly one integer $n$ which satisfies $x < n \leq x+1.$*

My attempt: From the theorem there is exactly one integer $n$ such that $n-1\le x<n$.This means that $n-1\le x\implies n\le x+1$. Therefore, this unique $n$ satisfies $x<n\le x+1$.

However, I don't think this is correct. Could someone please help? Thanks!

Comment: It's valid. But you have to show that $n$ is the only possible integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a small point, but uniqueness of $n$ in the Theorem does not necessarily translate to uniqueness of $n$ if you manipulate it in some way. To remedy this, you need to also show: if $n$ satisfies $x< n \leq x+1$, then $n$ satisfies $n \leq x < n+1$ (for which we know there is only one solution).

To see why uniqueness isn't automatic, consider:

**[False] Claim:** For any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists a unique $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $100x < m \leq 100(x+1)$.

**[False] Proof:** For any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists a unique $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $n-1 \leq x < n$. This unique $n$ satisfies $x<n \leq x+1$, and so $100x < 100n \leq 100(x+1)$. So $m=100n$ is the unique $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $100x<m \leq 100(x+1)$.

This is false, though, because if $x=1$, then $100x=100$ and $100(x+1)=200$, and there are many more than just one integer between these numbers. The uniqueness of $n$ from the theorem did not guarantee uniqueness in my false claim. In this case, having $m$ that satisfies the false claim does *not* necessarily imply there is $n$ satisfying the theorem, so we don't get a uniqueness statement.

Answer (score 1):

It's valid.

There is a unique element $m$ so that $m\le x < m+1$.  Let $n=m+1$ and $n-1 \le x < n$ so $x< n$ and $n-1+1 \le x+1$ so $n \le x+1$ so $x< n \le x+1$.

But we have prove this $n$ is unique.  Which is just a matter of doing in reverse.  If $x < m \le x+1$ then we have $x-1< m-1 \le x$ so $m-1\le x < m$.  But there The theorem says there is only one unique integer so that $n \le x < n+1$ so $m$ *must* equal $n+1$.

We can do this is a single argument.

There exists exact one unique integer $m$ so that $m \le x < m+1$.  Thus $m-1 \le x-1 < m \le x < m+1 \le x+1 < m+1$ and $m$ is unique in that regard.  So $n =m+1$ is an existing and unique integer so that $x< m \le x+1$